# search by category with php mysql

Tags: php, mysql, html, forms, get

hello im using this code to do search

```
    <form action="arama.php" method="get">
<input type="text" name="lol">
<select name='kategori'>
<option value="tum">Tum kategoriler</option>
<? 
while ($kat = mysql_fetch_array($kategori_isim)) {
echo "
<option value=".$kat[kategori_isim].">".$kat[kategori_isim]."</option>";
} 
?>
</select>
<input type="submit" value="ara">
</form>

<?
    $lol = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['lol']);
    $kategori = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['kategori']);

    if ($kategori == "tum") {
    $ara = mysql_query("select * from dosyalar where baslik like '%$lol%'");
    }
    else {
    $ara = mysql_query("select * from dosyalar where baslik like '%$lol%' order by kategori = '%$kategori%'");
    }
    ?>
```

search by term works but not listing by kategori.. what can i do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand the question (I can't really figure out what those fields mean), but I think that your second query should be more like:

```
$ara = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM dosyalar WHERE kategori LIKE '%$kategori%'");
```

`ORDER BY` only specifies how to sort the results, you can only use a column name, not a check as in your code.

Extending my answer: the `ORDER BY kategori = '%$kategori%'` isn't a syntax error but I don't think it does anything useful. The check `kategori = '%$kategori%'` will always be false (unless you have a value with percent signs both at start and at end) so the `ORDER BY` clause will be useless and you will just do the same select you're doing in the other branch of the `if` block.

Specifying `ORDER BY kategori = '$kategori'` will return 0 for all the records where `kategori` is not equal to `$kategori`, 1 for the ones where it matches. This will basically sort all the matching rows at the end of your query.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the query failed. In that case mysql_query() returns FALSE and mysql_error() returns a description of the error.
Try

```
<form action="arama.php" method="get">
  <input type="text" name="lol" />
  <select name='kategori'>
    <option value="tum">Tum kategoriler</option>
<?php 
while ( false!==($kat=mysql_fetch_array($kategori_isim)) ) {
  $htmlIsim = htmlspecialchars($kat['kategori_isim']);
  echo '    <option value="', $htmlIsim, '">', $htmlIsim, "</option>\n";
}
?>
  </select>
  <input type="submit" value="ara" />
</form>

<?php
$lol = isset($_GET['lol']) ? mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['lol']) : '';
$kategori = isset($_GET['kategori']) ? mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['kategori']) : '';
$query = "select * from dosyalar where baslik like '%$lol%'";
if ( 'tum'!==$kategori ) {
  $query .= "order by kategori = '%$kategori%'";
}
$ara = mysql_query($query) or die( htmlspecialchars(mysql_error().': '.$query) );
echo '<pre>Debug: ', mysql_num_rows($ara) , ' records in the result set for ', htmlspecialchars($query), "</pre>\n";
?>
```